# Obter Timezone do browser usando angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Preciso obter a timezone do navegador do usuário.
Como se trata de uma aplicação usando angularjs, resolvi usar a biblioteca do [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment)
Entretando não obtive sucesso em obter o nome da timezone.

O que preciso é uma maneira em angularjs de obter algo como : **'America/Sao_Paulo', 'Europa/Paris'**

Pensei em usar a biblioteca moment-timezone.js mas não consegui adicioná-la como dependencia no angular, pra poder usar no controler.

Comment: Além do moment você vai precisar do moment timezone para isso. http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

Adicionei a lib [JSTZ](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/)

```
<script src="js/jstz.min.js"></script>
```

No arquivo do controler inclui o seguinte código:

**/* jstz*/**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

....

})();
```

Ao adicionar o JSTZ no inicio do arquivo, consegui obter acesso a funções da biblioteca.
Assim dentro do controler executei o seguinte trecho:

```
var timezone = jstz.determine();
 console.log(timezone.name());
```

Cujo output foi : "America/Sao_Paulo"

Answer (score -1):

Se quiser quer o timezone do Browser formatado você pode contar com o método JavaScript (já que o angularjs é apenas um framework para se trabalhar com o mesmo) Date.toString e fazer:

```
var split = new Date().toString().split(" ");
var timeZoneFormatted = split[split.length - 2] + " " + split[split.length - 1];
```

Isso vai lhe retornar "GMT-0400 (EST)"  por exemplo, incluindo as actas de fuso horário quando aplicável.

Alternativamente, com regex você pode extrair qualquer parte desejada:

Para "GMT-0300 (EDT)" :

```
new Date().toString().match(/([A-Z]+[\+-][0-9]+.*)/)[1]
```

Para "GMT-0300" :

```
new Date().toString().match(/([A-Z]+[\+-][0-9]+)/)[1]
```

Somente "EDT" :

```
new Date().toString().match(/\(([A-Za-z\s].*)\)/)[1]
```

Somente "-0300":

```
new Date().toString().match(/([-\+][0-9]+)\s/)[1]
Date.toString reference:
```

Referencia do Date.toString:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString